# What does "wanted to have to" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does "wanted to have to" mean here?

> Now I have to go to the library which I never **wanted to have to** do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to go. = I must go. = I am required to go.

I don't want (to have to go) = I don't want (to be required to go).

I don't want to be required to go, and I *never* wanted to be required to go.

That may or may not mean that I don't want to go. It just means that I don't want it to be required.

Does that help at all?